# Jitsi / React JS: making host able to kick every participant out of room

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently making a video conferencing app using Node as backend and reactJS with Jitsi in frontend.
I am using Jitsi external API and react library jutsu(https://github.com/this-fifo/jutsu).
I want to enable moderator to kick every participant out of chat room when he closes the room.
I refer to another post the method is to loop thorough participants(https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/4e5397685287d8d87f29591546f7c902eac22bf0/JitsiConference.js#L1368)
and implement this kickParticipant method (https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/4e5397685287d8d87f29591546f7c902eac22bf0/JitsiConference.js#L1406).

I tried to add event listener participantJoined event, but I have not been able to even log the participants.

While passing disablingKick to true in jitsiConfig works and can disable the function of kicking users out.

Is there any config that can allow moderator kicking out participants, or at least getting the identity of moderator? Thank you!

My react code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Jutsu, useJitsi } from 'react-jutsu';
import {  Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
function VideoCreateRoom({userName, currentWorkspace}) {
    //room represents hashed room
        const [room, setRoom] = useState('')
        const [customRoomName, setCustomRoomName] = useState('')
        const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
        const [call, setCall] = useState(false)
        const [jitsiInit, setJitsiInit] = useState({});
        // const [hostEndMeeting, setHostEndMeeting] = useState(false);
        const grabParticipantIdArr = [];

        //Jitsi config
        //create a container for jitsi
        const jitsiContainerId = "jitsi-container-id";

        //add Jitsi meet api script 
        const loadJitsiScript = () => {
            let resolveLoadJitsiScriptPromise = null;

            const loadJitsiScriptPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolveLoadJitsiScriptPromise = resolve;
            });

            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = "https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js";
            script.async = true;
            script.onload = resolveLoadJitsiScriptPromise
            document.body.appendChild(script);

            return loadJitsiScriptPromise;
        };

        //load Jitsi Iframe
        const initialiseJitsi = async () => {
            if (!window.JitsiMeetExternalAPI) {
            await loadJitsiScript();
            }
            const myOverwrite ={
                 remoteVideoMenu: {
                        // If set to true the 'Kick out' button will be disabled.
                        disableKick: true
                    },
            }
            const options = {
                parentNode: document.getElementById(jitsiContainerId),
                // configOverwrite: myOverwrite
            }
            const _jitsi = new window.JitsiMeetExternalAPI("meet.jit.si", options); 
            setJitsiInit(_jitsi)
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            initialiseJitsi();
            return () => jitsiInit?.dispose?.();
            // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        }, []);

       
        const handleClick = async(event) =>{
            event.preventDefault();
            
            const body = { userName, currentWorkspace, customRoomName} 
            try{
                console.log('sending video room info to server')
                const sendVideo = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video`,{
                    method:"POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type":"application/json",
                        "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(body)
                })
                const response = await sendVideo.json();
                setPassword(response.password);
                setRoom(response.room);
                if (customRoomName) setCall(true);
                
            }catch(e){
                console.error(e.message);
            }
        }

           
        const jitsiConfig = {
            configOverwrite:
            {
                remoteVideoMenu:
                {
                    disableKick: false,
                },
            },
            
        }
        const { jitsi } = useJitsi(jitsiConfig);
        console.log( jitsi, 'console log for reactJS warning');

        const grabParticipantsId = () =>{
            const participants = jitsiInit.addEventListener('participantJoined', function(values){
                grabParticipantIdArr.push(values);
                console.log(grabParticipantIdArr, 'this is grabParticipantIdArr ');
            })
        }
        
        useEffect(()=>{
            console.log(jitsiInit)
            grabParticipantsId();
        }, [jitsiInit])

        return call ? ( 
            <>
            <h1>You are the host of this meeting.</h1>
            <h2>Room name: {customRoomName}</h2>
            <h2>Password for participants: {password}</h2>
            
            <Jutsu
            roomName={room}
            displayName={userName}
            password={password}
            onMeetingEnd={
                () => {
                    console.log('Meeting has end')
                }
            }
            loadingComponent={<p>loading ...</p>}
            errorComponent={<p>Oops, something went wrong</p>} 
            containerStyles={{width: '100%', height: '70%'}}
            configOverwrite= {jitsiConfig.configOverwrite}
            />
            </>
                    
        ) : (
            <>
            <form>
                <button onClick={handleClick} type='submit' target="_blank">
                    Start video conferencing
                </button>
                <input id='name' type='text' placeholder='Name' value={customRoomName} onChange={(e) => setCustomRoomName(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <button>
                <Link to ={`/workspace/${currentWorkspace}/video/rooms`}>
                    Check out video rooms
                </Link>
                
            </button>
            </>
            
    )
    }
    
    export default VideoCreateRoom
```

Answer (score 0):

```
api.getParticipantsInfo()
```

The function gets an array of participants
I have implemented it

```
api.addEventListener('participantJoined', () => {
                setParticipant(api.getParticipantsInfo())
            }
            )
```